# Error building for iOS simulator in hybrid app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I've been struggling with an error building my app with ionic and cordova.

Everything started when I tried a "ionic cordova build ios --prod --release". It retrieved an error regarding FirebaseAnalytics for architecture arm64

```
"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"
```

Reinstalling the pods and removing and adding the ios platform again I got this error even without the --release flag.

```
error: Building for iOS Simulator, but the embedded framework 'WebRTC.framework' was built for iOS. (in target 'Qvadis' from project 'Qvadis')
```

and I'm stuck here and I don't know if something changed with the latest XCode version (12.0) or the latest iOS version (14) or I have a dependencies problem.

Before that, it compiled just fine.

Thank you in advance,
Borja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

In Build Settings, selecting your app as Target, you have to type "arm64" in "Excluded architectures".

However, this doesn't allow you to archive and publish it so you have to remove the "arm64" excluded architecture to perform those actions.

I don't know if this is a good approach, but this is the one that works for me.